# Error: Type Queue Does Not Take Parameter - What's the difference between Queues and Priority Queues?

Tags: java, collections, parameters, queue, stack

I get the error message Type Queue does not Take Parameters. When I replace alter the Queue line to a PriorityQueue this error disappears and it compiles fine. What is the difference and how can I change it to compile and a regular queue?

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackOneTwoMultiply {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int first, second;

        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();  //stack called s
        PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {      //filling the stack (what order to fill was not specifified)
            s.push(i);
        }

        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            first = s.pop();
            second = s.pop();
            q.offer(first * second);
            System.out.println(q.peek());
        }

        System.out.print(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry you mean `Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();` ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the vagueness.

Comment: But you can create Queue because it is `abstract` class. You can create it as here: `Queue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();`

Comment: You can create `Stack` because it is not `abstract`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Queue instead of PriorityQueue create and object of LinkedList class with Queue interface.

```
import java.util.*;
.....
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
.....
```

and if it doesn't work even after this then try using specified import statements :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
```

Sometimes it happens that it won't accept parameters with java.util.*

[code snippet of error due to java.util.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MKln.png)

Comment: That last part did me in... 
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
**Sometimes it happens that it won't accept parameters with java.util**

Answer (score 1):

`Queue` itself is not a concrete class (it's an interface), and therefore cannot be instantiated. `PriorityQueue` is, however, a concrete implementation of `Queue` and so may be instantiated.